# I have 3 columns and one of the column have a value of 1 and the others with a value of 0. How can I get the column name which have the value 1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are four columns which are Single, Married and Divorced - and one of the columns values will have a value of 1 and the others with a value of 0.

I have created a separate column with MaritalStatus and I want to get the column name which have the value 1?

UNIQUE,
COUNTIF,
IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd> & <kbd>REPT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell D2

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,REPT($A$1:$C$1,A2:C2>0))
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>BYROW( )</kbd> to spill

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=BYROW(A2:C4,LAMBDA(b,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($A$1:$C$1,b>0))))
```

---

Solution provided in OP's google sheet link

[image]

---

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The cell responds with #VALUE!  error. Can you help me on this document - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GZcVz04H8hpMUl07CzfK0uMrE0tjBl3RwSRIQMaL1_8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AbelZewdu i have updated the solution in your given google sheet link. please check and confirm

Answer (score 1):

> *"...one of the columns values will have a value of 1 and the others with a value of 0..."*

Looks like the following will do for you:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=TOCOL(IF(A2:C5,A1:C1,NA()),3)
```